# How to get posts from many categories using WP_Query

Tags: categories, query

I'm trying to get posts from multiple specific categories.

This is my code:

```
$myquery= new WP_Query( array(
  'posts_per_page'=>7,
  'cat' => array(5,3,7),
) );
```

It isn't working - what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the code for getting posts from multiple categories using `WP_Query`

Just correct the cat value, it is used without an array. Check out [Codex: WP_Query - Category Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters) link for more information.

```
WP_Query( array(
  'posts_per_page' => 7,
  'cat' => '5,3,7',
) );
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It Works Fine. How can I do this for search and authors?!

Comment: For Multiple Authors use $query = new WP_Query( array( 'author__in' => array( 2, 6 ) ) );

Comment: For Search parameter use $query = new WP_Query( array( 's' => 'keyword' ) ); It is also used by wordpress default search.

Comment: 'author__in' works fine, but  's' => 'keyword' works only for one keyword. I need to get posts for many search keyword, 's' => 'keyword 1', 'keyword 2', 'keyword 3'